# Form height and width measured differently than TextBox height

Tags: c#, winforms, components

I'm using a function to create textboxes for a class for making arrays of textboxes, and I want to center the grid to the form. After some debugging, I realized that the form height and width are measured on a different scale than the width and height of the textboxes. 
Values for variables:

- height = 50
- width = 50
- numCols = 10
- numRows = 10
- vertCellOffset = 50
- horzCellOffset = 50

  ```
  private TextBox AddNewTextBox()
  {
      SOSTextBox txtBox = new SOSTextBox();
      this.List.Add(txtBox);
      hostForm.Controls.Add(txtBox);
      txtBox.Height = height;
      txtBox.Width = width;
      float scrnWidth = hostForm.Width;
      float scrnHeight = hostForm.Height;
      txtBox.Top = (int)(((int)((Count - 1) / numCols) + 1) * vertCellOffset + (scrnHeight / 2 - ((numRows / 2 + 1) * vertCellOffset)));
      txtBox.Left = (int)((((Count - 1) % numCols) + 1) * horzCellOffset + (scrnWidth / 2 - ((numCols / 2 + 1) * horzCellOffset)));
      txtBox.ArrayLocation = new Point ((Count - 1) / numCols, (Count - 1) % numCols);
      txtBox.Tag = Count;
      txtBox.Font = new Font(txtBox.Font.FontFamily, height / 6.0f); // makes font size 1/3 of the height of textBox
      txtBox.Text = "\r\n";
      txtBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(KeyPressHandler);
      return txtBox;
  }
  ```

Comment: They are measured in exactly the same scale.  But they would not be placed from the same origin.  The form would have a location relative to the screen on which it sits, the textboxes would be relative to the container in which they reside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a question here, but the textboxes and the form are both "measured" in pixels. What you need to be concerned with is the forms ClientSize or ClientRectangle (both are also in pixels).

If your form is not autosizing, then in the forms Load event you can call SetClientSizeCore(width, height), where width and height is the size of the "box" that holds all your texstboxes.